# Syntax Error on PDO sql statment

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I got a problem in this code in the sql statement ($result). It says that I have a Syntax error on `WHERE 'idCartao'='$id'`.

```
<?php
$db_host        = 'localhost';
$db_user        = 'root';
$db_pass        = '';
$db_database    = 'hsa'; 
$id = $_POST['idTAG'];
        try {
            $db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$db_host.';dbname='.$db_database, $db_user, $db_pass);
        } 
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
            die();
}
            $result = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO 'cartao' (horaEntrada,horaSaida) VALUES (CURTIME(),CURTIME()) WHERE 'idCartao'='$id'");
            $result->execute();
$db = null;
?>
```

Comment: You can not add WHERE clause in Insert query

Comment: Maybe you are looking for UPDATE clause (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html)

Comment: Besides that you can't add a `WHERE` clause to an `INSERT` statement, you shouldn't enclose column names with `''` but enclose it with ``

Comment: Try changing your question title to something more descriptive of the problem.

Comment: Too many things wrong with this query.

Comment: Your open to SQL Injection attack as you've not used prepared statements properly. Also any and all user submitted data must be **validated** before it gets anywhere near to the database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) In SQL anything quoted within `''` is a string. You cannot use it as a column/table/database name. MySQL specifically offers quoting for columns/tables/databases using ``` `` ``` and it is generally good practice to use it as to escape MySQL reserved keywords when using such keywords as data names.

2) `INSERT ... VALUES` does not work with `WHERE` you probably intended to use `UPDATE`? Not sure, not clear from the question.

3) You should also know how to use prepared statements properly.

Overall you'd probably need to do the following:

```
$result = $db->prepare("UPDATE `cartao` SET `horaEntrada`=CURTIME(),`horaSaida`=CURTIME() WHERE `idCartao`=:id");    
$result->execute([ ":id" => $id ]);
```